# No intellisense for 'com.facebook.react:react-native' in Android Studio

Tags: java, react-native, android-studio, build.gradle, maven-central

I am building a react-native library with java and so I need to use the package 'com.facebook.react:react-native'. To use the package I added the line `implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0'` to my build.gradle file. The code runs without any error, but I don't have intellisense for the library in Android Studio. It seems to not be able to download the package descriptions for some reason and I can't figure out why this is not working but the app is. Did someone have the same issue and was able to get intellisense to work? My Android Studio version is: 'Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1'.

I tried synching the build.gradle file again and looked at the logs, but apparently the download of the pom file failed as can be seen in this picture. [Fetching pom files failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtcUD.png). When I looked up the url's in my browser I get an 404 Not Found error from both websites.

I also tried clearing the cache and restarting Android Studio, but that did not help as well and the same problem occured.

Then I tried to download it manually from the maven central website https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/versions. When I click on browse, I get an 404 Not Found error. It seems like something is not online that should be there and I wasn't able to download it manually.
I have waited a week to see if something just happened to the server and someone fix it, but that was not the case so I need another solution.